# rake db:migrate実行時のエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rake db:migrateを実行すると以下のようなエラーになります。
どなたか考えられる対処法をお教えいただけないでしょうか。
プログラミング初心者で、いろいろ調べましたがどうにもいかず…

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `register_preprocessor' for nil:NilClass
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/i18n-js-3.0.0.rc11/lib/i18n/js/engine.rb:10:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:443:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
```

Comment: これだけの情報だと`rvm`を使ってることと`ubuntu`で実行しているらしい、ということ以外は、initializerの実行でエラーになっていること以外何も読み取れないのではないでしょうか。質問者さんも何を提示したら理解してもらえるのかわからないのかもしれませんが、これだけだと答えを得るのは難しいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) のIssueを確認したところ、先週末にリリースされた [sprocket-rails 3.0.0](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/releases/tag/v3.0.0) と組み合わせるとそのようなエラーが出るという報告が挙がっていました。で、昨日 master ブランチで修正されたようです。

[Doesn't work with sprocket-rails v3.0 · Issue #378 · fnando/i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/issues/378)

あなたの環境にインストールされた sprocket-rails のバージョンがわからないので断言はできませんが、恐らくこれだと思います。インストール済みのバージョンは `bundle show` で確認できるかと思います。

まだこれを含んだ i18n-js の新バージョンはリリースされていませんが、とりあえず Gemfile の記述を以下のように修正することで試してみることができるかと思います。

```
gem 'i18n-js', :github => 'fnando/i18n-js'
```

もちろん、正式にリリースされたら元の記述に戻すことをお勧めします。

Comment: Gemfileを書き換えたところ、上述のエラーはなくなりました。
今度は以下のようなエラーが出ましたが、また別問題だと思いますので、解決済みにさせていただきます。ありがとうございました。
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?